# How best to relate historical testing data to a shapefile?

Tags: attribute-joins, time, relates

I am tasked with bringing what has historically been only tracked in Excel into a shapefile. I am using ArcMap, but also have QGIS installed on my computer

What these shapefiles will include is inventory and location information about the road segment being tested which is easy enough to do. 
The problem I have is that the agency I am doing this workfor also wants all their historical testing data to be included in these shapefiles (done yearly and there are about 10 numbers to keep track of each year). Now the only thing that I can think of is adding a prefix to indicate the year (2002_Friction or something) and then each column of testing, but that would result in a ridiculously huge number of columns. I am going to have to probably do this several dozen times at the minimum so I'm trying to find an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Would a field containing the years suffice?

Comment: Can you create a table with inspection information and then relate that back to your spatial data, that way you can have several inspections in one table but still only one spatial feature.